# I have doc file which i want to convert into pdf using itext in java..how to do this things?

Tags: java, itext

Don't understand what to do. I added latest version of iText jar file but not getting the solution.
please give me correct solution or code. please mention it stepwise. because I'm doing this first time...

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you ran into problems. Just asking for a solution without showing any effort will not get you any answers on SO.

Comment: Using iText isn't sufficient. You need an add-on on top of iText. I'm forwarding this to the person at iText Group who can help you. If he doesn't have the time to answer, I suggest you contact iText Group directly.

Comment: i have template which make docs files ...now as requirement i have to make pdf files from that doc files..but i did not know how that such things happen in iText...and as i mention i'm doing this first time so totally blank.

Comment: You mean doc file (binary format) or docx file (zip which contains XML entries)? If you wish to convert docx -> pdf, XDocReport can help you and it is based on iText. If you use it and you have problem, please create an issue at https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't solve your use case as easily as you think. iText does not support Word to PDF conversion, because this requires very good knowledge of the OOXML format.

I'm an employee at iText Software, and for the last few weeks I've been investigating XDocReport, a tool that lets users manipulate MS Word files (DOCX) and OpenOffice/LibreOffice files (ODF). They also have a plugin that converts DOCX or ODF to PDF, with iText. Users that want this functionality can choose whether to use iText 2 under the LGPL license or iText 5 under the AGPL license.

XDocReport has already done an excellent job creating their converter tool with the limited human resources they have, and I've also made some minor progress on the project with fixing bugs and layout problems. However, there are still a lot of things that need fixing in order to make the PDFs closely resemble the MS Word documents.

The XDocReport has documentation for using their plugins, but it is not an easy thing to do, and you need to know a lot about Maven and dependencies to make it work. I've created a plugin discovery project to make that easier, but we haven't released it yet: as of now it doesn't produce the quality in PDFs that we feel our customers would want. We have no timeline for availability of this plugin.